# MDC-Web via CDN with individual components: window.mdc.autoInit is not a function

Tags: material-components-web

We are starting with MDC-Web with an older Ruby on Rails 3.2 application.

When including the whole MDC-Web package (CSS + JS) things work, but we encounter problems when trying to use individual packages of MDC-Web.

When we use the individual packages, we get an error "window.mdc.autoInit is not a function".

Our code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Log in</title>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700,900">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@material/textfield@0.35.0/dist/mdc.textfield.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@material/button@0.35.0/dist/mdc.button.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material/textfield@0.35.0/dist/mdc.textfield.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material/ripple@0.35.0/dist/mdc.ripple.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material/auto-init@0.35.0/dist/mdc.autoInit.min.js"></script>

<style>

:root {
  --mdc-theme-primary: #4F9593; /* this changes the color of all buttons */
  --mdc-theme-on-primary: #ffffff; /* this is the text color on the buttons */
  --mdc-theme-accent: #64dd17;
  --mdc-theme-secondary: #ffffff;
}


.mdc-button.primary-filled-button {
   --mdc-theme-primary: #fb641b;
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="mdc-text-field" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">
<input class="mdc-text-field__input" type="text" id="input">
<label for="input" class="mdc-floating-label">Email</label>
<div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>

<button class= "mdc-button mdc-button--raised primary-filled-button" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCRipple" >
Log in
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.mdc.autoInit();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything is fine when we use the complete packages (commented out above), but fails when we include only the individual packages which results in an error in the JS console of the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.mdc.autoInit is not a function
```

window.mdc.autoInit does exist when we check in the console:

```
> window.mdc.autoInit
{default: ƒ, __esModule: true}
default:ƒ r()
  __esModule:true
  __proto__:Object
```

But is not a function.

Does anyone have an idea what we are doing wrong / how we can solve this ? (we would like to use individual MDC-web packages to avoid conflicts with bootstrap which we use in the rest of the site while we migrate bit by bit.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code from:

```
window.mdc.autoInit();
```

to

```
mdc.autoInit();
```